# JSON.Net Convert inner object to C# Model

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following JSON coming back from a remote API (I cannot modify the JSON returned)

```
{
    "APITicket": {
        "location": "SOMEVALUE",
        "ticket": "SOMEVALUE"
    }
}
```

Now using JSON.Net to convert to this to a model I have to create 2 models.

```
  public class TicketModel
    {
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string ticket { get; set; }
    }

    public class TicketContainer
    {
        public TicketModel APITicket { get; set; } 
    }
```

and do something like..

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TicketContainer>(this.JSONResponse);
```

and this works well - my problem arises when I have around 50 calls to make to the API and really dont fancy creating a second 'Container' for each. Is there a way to bind the example above directly to the TicketModel?

Comment: If you need to deserialise in between every API call then there is really no way around this. You could batch deserialise after the 50 API calls have returned.

Comment: Hi @SamLeach I have 50 different API calls so it's not a quantity of calls but more just a pain in creating Container models that just are not useful for anything but the Deserialize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var json = @"
            {
                'APITicket': {
                    'location': 'SOMEVALUE',
                    'ticket': 'SOMEVALUE'
                }
            }";

//Parse the JSON:
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

//Select the nested property (we expect only one):
var jProperty = (JProperty)jObject.Children().Single();

//Deserialize it's value to a TicketModel instance:
var ticket = jProperty.Value.ToObject<TicketModel>();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Newtonsoft's JArray` to **customize ur json before deserialize**

```
public List<APITicket> JsonParser(string json)   
    {
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jArray = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(json);

        var list = new List<APITicket>();

        foreach(var item in jArray)
        {
            list.Add(
                new APITicket { location = item["APITicket"]["location"],
                                ticket =   item["APITicket"]["ticket"]            
                }
            );
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the JSON so it looks like this

```
{
    "location": "SOMEVALUE",
    "ticket": "SOMEVALUE"
}
```

and do

```
List<TicketModel> tickets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TicketModel>>(this.JSONResponse);
```

or even

```
Dictionary<string, string> tickets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(this.JSONResponse);
```

so you don't need any models.

Comment: Hi Sam, I cant modify the JSON as it's an external API. - Updated question to clarify.

Comment: Why not? If it's returned Json, you can do what you want with it.